# JQuery - Collapsable DIV: Easy way to remember state of opened div?

Tags: php, jquery

This is what I have for a simple collapsable div (opens/closes on click of a toggle button)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a></div>
```

```
.slidingDiv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}

.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Now, the function works perfectly, but if I open the div and then navigate the page, the div obviously goes back to being closed on reload/clicking a link etc..

Is there an easy way to add a remembered state so that during the entire user experience the div remains open when he clicks to open it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options.

First is make an AJAX call to save the state of the div in for example a session variable using PHP.

Or perhaps even better make use off HTML5's offline storage.

However I don't know what the browser support is for offline storage.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a cookie on the users machine using javascript?

You can read more here .... http://w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JQuery cookie plugin, that would make it a little easier:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie